# How can I give validation on decimal field in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `Order` model, which has a decimal `:total`. I want to validate that this total is two decimal places, greater than 0, and is less than a million.

```
validates :total, presence: true, format: { with: /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/ }, numericality: { greater_than: 0, less_than: 100_000_000 }
```

When my total becomes `1234567890.00`, it raises an error:

> PG::NumericValueOutOfRange: ERROR: numeric field overflow DETAIL: A field with precision 11, scale 2 must round to an absolute value less than 10^9. : UPDATE "orders" SET "tax_total" = $1, "total" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "orders"."id" = $4

I also tried to add this migration:

```
def self.up
  change_column :orders, :total, :decimal, :precision => 11, :scale =>2
end
```

in my model, but the error is still there.

I want validation message [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEeZ1.png).

Comment: your number is to big for your database field. the error has nothing to do with rails validation

Comment: Yes, i know so, here how can i show proper error message instead of this  PG::NumericValueOutOfRange:

Comment: sorry now i get it, does the validator work if you insert some other wrong stuff like `12.123.1` or `abc` ?

Comment: Yes, it work when i insert 122.34 or abc

Comment: So the validation seems to work as intended, expect when the number is to big? does the validation also work with a negative number?

Comment: No, it's give me error when i insert negative number or 1223.00

Comment: what error do you get on negative numbers?

Comment: @messages={:total=>["can't be blank", "is invalid", "is not a number"]}

Comment: so the `:total` field seems to be empty now. start debugging on where your problem exactly lies, we can't help you otherwise

Comment: The validation looks good. Please show the code how you save that number to database. Some AR methods bypass validation.

Comment: The [numericality validation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality) does not have an option for testing the number of decimals. So you will need to [write your own validation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations). The easiest way I can think of is casting the value to a string and using a regular expression such as [`/^\d+$|\d*\.\d{1,2}/`](http://rubular.com/r/p9RZPIxVHJ).

Comment: Or `x == x.round(2)`

Answer (score 2):

For 1234567890.00 to fit in, your migration should be

```
def self.up
    change_column :orders, :total, :decimal, :precision => 12, :scale =>2
end
```

For validating numericality of number use the following at the rails level:

```
validates_numericality_of :decimal, less_than_or_equal_to: BigDecimal(10**8)
```

Remember, precision is the total number - (mantissa + characteristic)
For your case 1234567890 add up to 10. Add 2 for decimal to this and that's how your precision should be 12 rather than 11.

Comment: Neeraj, here is my precision 11, because it's my client requirement,my issue is when my total is greater then 100,000,000 then it's give me proper validation msg somthing like "You can't create a single invoice for more than 100,000,000". but here when my total is greater then 1000,000,000 it's give me server error. i want proper validation error instead of this server error.

Comment: That you may handle on the rails level
Use 
`validates_numericality_of :decimal, less_than_or_equal_to: BigDecimal(10**8)`

Also note that scale = 2 in the migration will round the decimals up to 2 places when you save the data

Comment: Can, you please add it in your answer box? suitable for my case.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks! Neeraj i tried that type but still my issue not solved!

Comment: Please tell me your exact issue then.